# Word addin not loading on second Word document

Tags: ms-word, add-in, office-2003

Ive written a Word addin in VS 2008 thats pretty simple, just adds a commandbar and a couple of buttons.

The addin loads and works fine for the first document that is opened.

When I open a second and subsequent documents, the addin does not load.

Please ask for anymore info if needed. Happy to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, after a couple of days working on this issue, I finally found the solution.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/officedeveloperVisualBasica/Aug2005/post23498818.asp

I wasn't assigning a unique tag to each of my buttons!

```
newButton.Tag = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Voila!